# Git full commands hierarchy

Tags: git

I recently discovered the Git command `hash-object` which to belong to the deepest level of Git. I will be not surprised if this command is implicitly used in other commands like `commit`. I know for example that `update-ref` is used in `git branch`.

Other commands like `pull` are in fact a combinaison of a `fetch` followed by a `merge`. `git clone` is also a non-command because it does a `mkdir`, a `git init` and a `git pull`.

Other commands like `show` may be somehow related to `cat-file`.

We also find other types of commands like `difftool` that are not really commands but scripts. These belongs to what I want to call the highest level.

I am wondering if I can find a graphical representation of all the git commands classed by level and relationship, from the plumbing to the porcelain commands.

This would help me to get a much better understanding of Git commands and  it might be a very nice as a poster in my office :)

Is there any nice tree representation of all the Git commands down from the obscure plumbing commands to the high end porcelain tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Atlassian Git Cheat Sheet**. Its a pretty good visual sheet having the Git commands with their basic description alongside.

https://www.atlassian.com/dms/wac/images/landing/git/atlassian_git_cheatsheet.pdf

There's another good graphical representation for the Git commands on **git-tower.com**. Here, you can find all the important commands along with best practices for Version Control.

http://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-cheat-sheet/

Finally, **Github.com** has also provided a Git Cheat Sheet. You can look into that also.

https://services.github.com/on-demand/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf

**A Sample Screenshot of Git-Tower's Cheat Sheet:**

[image: git-tower]

Comment: However it is missing all the low level commands like `update-ref` `cat-file`, `write-tree` or `read-tree`. These commands are the basic working pieces of Git and the Idea is to connect them to middle-level commands